# General malaise after workout for the whole day or sometimes 2 days. Is it normal?

Tags: workout-routines, pain

I've been working out, but never regularly, for the last 5 - 6 years now. I just resumed my workout schedule with some regularity (10 - 12 days a month or so) a couple of months ago.

After my workout, I feel very tired and a general malaise or discomfort throughout the rest of the day and sometimes even on the following day. It takes about 2 - 3 days for me to feel completely rested and rejuvenated again.

Is this something I will just have to get used to or is there something that I can do to improve the way I feel post workout?

Comment: Thank you, Chad. I asked because I am in discomfort and am waiting to get over this phase. I hope it will go and I want to know if there comes a time when you feel just alright after working out and don't feel this way, or does this sort of a thing remain your entire life, i.e. after every workout for the rest of your life?

Comment: Can you give us more details?  Age, are you overweight, what types of workouts are you doing, any other health issues?  Could be too much too soon.  Could be a million things.

Answer (score 2):

The condition of post exercise fatigue (and from a previous question you posted - fatigue during exercise) could be related to MANY causes.  The best approach is to see a doctor immediately, since the causes include diabetes, heart condition, etc.  It could also be something as simple of pre-workout nutrition.  Be safe and see a Dr.